# Is it possible to select 2 measures in different axis in MDX?

Tags: ssas, mdx, mondrian

I have a question regarding MDX queries :

I have a SUBSCRIPTION cube about magazine subscriptions with two measures : NEW SUBS. and RETURNING SUBS.

I'm trying to make a query that displays both measures for two periods of time, and also the percentage growth in the period.

**Example :**

[DESIRED VIEW - EXAMPLE](http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/1415/xcg5.png)

But I can't get this view using standard MDX, because I can't put measures in both axis.

**The result I've got so far (not user friendly):**

Using measure ON COLUMNS:

[RESULT - NOT USER FRIENDLY](http://img62.imageshack.us/img62/9025/1aei.png)

**How can I do that first view using MDX formulas?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Make `growth` a member of your time hierarchy like this:

```
WITH MEMBER [Time].[Calendar Date].[Growth] AS
     [Time].[Calendar Date].[Jan-12] / [Time].[Calendar Date].[Jan-13] - 1
     ,format_string="0%"
SELECT { [Time].[Calendar Date].[Jan-12], [Time].[Calendar Date].[Jan-13], [Time].[Calendar Date].[Growth] }
       ON COLUMNS,
       { Measures.NEW, Measures.RETURNING }
       ON ROWS
  FROM [SUBSCRIPTION]
```

I was guessing some names of your cube, you will have to adapt the MDX to your situation.

Calculated members need not be a member of the measures hierarchy, they can be used on every hierarchy of your cube. And to answer the question in the title of your question: No, one hierarchy can only be used in one axis in an MDX query.